# jQuery prepend only to next list item after each click, not all list items at once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Simply put, my goal is to make the "next" button add a class active to the previous list item, then if the active class exists, also prepend a YES to that list item, not all list items as it is currently doing in my code.

Currently, my attempt is adding YES to all list items, I want to add YES only to the previous items after each click.

My attempt is here:

```
var $tabs = $('li');    

$('.next').on('click', function () {
    $tabs.next('li').addClass("active").css("background-color","yellow");

  if ($($tabs).next().hasClass("active")){
      $($tabs).prepend('YES').prev();
    } else {
        $($tabs).append('NO');
    }

});
```

Code can be seen here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yrjvb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but this might be what you're looking for :

```
var $tabs = $('li');
var count = 0;

$('.next').click(function () {
  var tab = $tabs.eq(count);   
  var link = tab.find('a[data-toggle="tab"]');
  link.addClass("active").css("background-color","yellow");

  if (link.hasClass("active")) {
    tab.prepend('YES');
    count++;
  } else {
    tab.append('NO');
  }
});
```

Forked Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pnKAc?editors=101

Basically, you were selecting all the `<li>` items. In my code, I select an item one-by-one.

Surely there is a better way to do it (selecting directly the next element etc., but I guess with this code you can see what's different.

Also, you say you want to add, did you mean "append", then ?

Comment: Great solution, the count is what I was missing! Like in your code, I wanted to select items one by one, I meant add to the html with prepend, which puts the html before, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach ([codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/moEfd)):  Store the current one, clear its active state, pick the next one ?

```
$('.next').on('click', function () {
  var $current = $('li.active');
  if(!$current.length){
    $current = $('li:first');
    $current.addClass('active');
  }else{
    $current.removeClass('active');
    $current.next('li').addClass('active');
  }   
 });
```